# How to import a directory tree into Darktable

Tags: photo-management

When I try to "Import Filmroll" into Darktable, I can't see how to tell it to include all subdirectories. Any tips?

Comment: Wow, that is gonna be a real headache for anyone migrating from an app which uses a .../year/month/day directory structure! Thanks for the responses.

Comment: If you still want to use Darktable, there is video about how it works [here](http://blog.pcode.nl/2010/07/15/darktable-overview-screencast/).

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll test it out on a few files and see if I want to spend an afternoon importing my photos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Soo, current master includes a recursive adding a directory and its files, and a option for not including jpegs files, which is good if you shoot raw+jpeg...
Release 0.7 would include this and if you run unstable PPA you have this option now..

Answer (score 2):

In Darktable 1.1 when importing a folder, you can expand "import options" and check the "import directories recursively" option.

Answer (score 1):

I asked in the #darktable IRC channel on Freenode and it's currently not implemented yet, but it's on the TODO-list.  It's probably very easy to implement but the core developers are currently working on some other features that require their skills.

If you know a bit of C++ programming, or you know somebody who wants to help with it, it's probably less than a day's work to implement this and contribute it to the project...

Answer (score 1):

i'm one of the developer for darktable, and i have the same "problem" with my f-spot library of images, the best way to do this migration is to use a script wich can migrate the library including the tags/colorlabels and migrating into the storage structure defined in darktable camera import dialog.

i know that someone have started to work on a script for lightroom migration but i dont know the status for it, and im probly the one who makes the f-spot migration script..

/Henrik

Comment: I'd love to know a bit more about the storage structure, and how to get darktable to reconize that I've dumped more files into it's storage tree (so that it can update whatever internal databases it keeps), so that I can give it a shot. Could you please point me in the right direction? (I'm importing from Lightroom, so I'll be content with dropping the meta-data and just getting all the photos into Darktable's database).

Comment: The camera import dialog (settings tab) would tell the tail how storage structure is built while importing from camera, this is NOT the case when importing single image or directory.

Comment: the process would be: enumeration of images from source (lightroom) with some limiting such as tag, construct physical directorystructure matching darktable structure, add entry into darktabledatabase for the new filmroll and each image..

Comment: forgot to tell, use tag as $(jobcode)

Answer (score 0):

A general note on migrating a library to Darktable:

For example F-Spot structures like this:

~/Pictures/2010/10/19/IMG_1234.CR2

Now Darktable uses the top level directory as the filmroll name "19" in that case, which would easily conflict. So I'd recommend a directory tree like so:

~/Darktable/2010/20101019_ShortEventDescription/IMG_1234.CR2 (or even PMJ_20101019_1234.CR2 in my case).

In this case your filmroll would be called "20101019_ShortEventDescription" which is quite unique and a bit descriptive of the contents...